# How do we change the Paypal account on our Facebook game from our developers account in the USA to our account in Australia

Tags: facebook, paypal

We have a game on Facebook developed by a 3rd party developer in the USA & the Paypal account where in game purchases end up is the developers account in the USA.

We are based in Australia and want the funds that are generated deposited directly to our Paypal account.

How would our developer do this?

Comment: Ask them to do it, they're the author and the one you hired, they should be SLR to switch the account number

Answer (score 1):

In Answer to your question, it depends on how your developer integrated with PayPal.
 
If it is a **PayPal Standard Integration** all that is needed is to change the email address in your face book app. PayPal Standard uses confirmed email addresses for integration purposes. 
[PayPal Standard Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/gs_PayPalPaymentsStandard/)
If it is an **Express Checkout integration** then you need to obtain the API Signature credentials from your new Australian Account.
[PayPal Express Checkout Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/)
If it was a **PayPal Payments Advanced** or **PayPal Payments Pro** Setup, then you will need to ensure that your Australian account is setup for those products, and then you just need the PayPal Manager credentials to integrate.
[PayPal Pro/Advanced Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/gs_PayPalPaymentsPro/)
The first thing that would be best for you is to ask your developer if he used PayPal Payments Standard, PayPal Payments Pro, Express Checkout or PayPal Payments Advanced. Once you determine how the account was integrated your developer should be able to change the credentials.
Here is the link to the PayPal Developer Documentation. It has all the different ways to integrate with PayPal:
[PayPal Developer Integration](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/)